# can not test api 32 it says invalid date string: Unparseable date: "bb`baiahbgbdGMT+00:00"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I want test fun but i have error it says
invalid date string: Unparseable date: "bb`baiahbgbdGMT+00:00"
I use emulator api 32 and can not run test

```
> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
?? actionable tasks: ? executed, ?? up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid date string: Unparseable date: "bb`baiahbgbdGMT+00:00"
```

this code I want to test this sample from android doc

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    val TEST_STRING = "This is a string"
    val TEST_LONG = 12345678L
    lateinit var mLogHistory: LogHistory

    @Before
    fun createLogHistory() {
        mLogHistory = LogHistory()
    }

    @Test
    fun logHistory_ParcelableWriteRead() {
        // Set up the Parcelable object to send and receive.
        mLogHistory.addEntry(TEST_STRING, TEST_LONG)

        // Write the data
        val parcel = Parcel.obtain()
        mLogHistory!!.writeToParcel(parcel, mLogHistory!!.describeContents())

        // After you're done with writing, you need to reset the parcel for reading.
        parcel.setDataPosition(0)

        // Read the data
        val createdFromParcel: LogHistory = LogHistory.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel)
        val createdFromParcelData: List<Pair<String, Long>> = createdFromParcel.data

        // Verify that the received data is correct.
        assertThat(createdFromParcelData.size).isEqualTo(1)
        assertThat(createdFromParcelData[0].first).isEqualTo(TEST_STRING)
        assertThat(createdFromParcelData[0].second).isEqualTo(TEST_LONG)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the language of the windows and the format of date and time

Comment: I solved that it is not language windows just change some settings in projects

Comment: also if you just change the language and date and time to english USA and make it as default language .. after that restart the computer it will be fixed .. i faced it 11 hours ago.

Comment: My device is mainly in English